# How can I benchmark different languages / frameworks?

Tags: php, asp.net, python, frameworks, benchmarking

I'd like to compare the performance of different languages and/or different frameworks within the same language. This is aimed at server-side languages used for web development. I know an apples to apples comparison is not possible, but I'd like it to be as unbiased as possible. Here are some ideas :

- Simple "Hello World" page
- Object initialization
- Function/method calls

  - Method bodies will range from empty to large
- File access (read and write)
- Database access

They can either be measured by Requests per second or I can use a `for` loop and loop many times. Some of these benchmarks should measure the overhead the language has (ie: empty function call) rather than how fast they perform a certain task. I'll take some precautions:

- They'll run on the same machine, on fresh installations with as few processes on the background as possible.
- I'll try and set up the server as officially recommended; I will not attempt any optimizations.

How can I improve on this?

Comment: What are you trying to understand or discover? Are you looking for which is the best language for your needs?

Comment: You can look at other benchmarks and explain what you want to do that they aren't doing, or they don't do well, such as this site: http://www.timestretch.com/FractalBenchmark.html

Comment: @James Just how fast a language or framework is. Yes, and no to your second question. Performance alone doesn't mean anything, but it's a factor I'd like to consider.

Comment: @NullUserException - Fast how?  For example, if you compare a script version of Groovy to C that would be unfair, as this Groovy code would need to be compiled first.  Are you looking at scientific computing for speed, how fast it can render 3D graphics? Constraints are important for the comparison to be meaningful. For example, if I write unit tests to see the fastest language combination for client-server applications, that is a focused group of tests, and was useful to me.

Comment: @James That is exactly what I want to avoid (unfair comparisons). I'll be comparing languages that will be used for web development.

Comment: Your question is ambiguos and confusing!.. If I could, I would close this question, but hopefully others will do me the favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done is to write many unit tests so you can test the layers.

For example, write a SOAP web service in PHP, Python and C#.

Write a REST web service in the same languages (same web services, just two ways to get to them). This one should be able to return JSON and XML as a minimum.

Write unit tests in C# and Python to serve as clients, and test the REST with the various result types (XML/JSON).  This is important as later you may need to test to see which is best end-to-end, and JSON may be faster to parse than XML, for you (it should be).

So, the REST/SOAP services should go to the same controller, to simplify your life.

This controller needs tests, as you may need to later remove it's impact on your tests, but, you can also write tests to see how fast it goes to the database.

I would use one database for this, unless you want to evaluate various databases, but for a web test, just do that for phase 2. :)

So, what you end up with is lots of tests, each test needs to be able to determine how long it took for it to actually run.

You then have lots of numbers, and you can start to analyze to see what works best for you.

For example, I had learned (a couple of years ago when I did this) that JSON was faster than XML, REST was faster than SOAP.

You may find that some things are much harder to do in some languages and so drop them from contention as you go through this process.

Writing the tests is the easy part, getting meaningful answers from the numbers will be the harder part, as your biases may color your analysis, so be careful of that.

I would do this with some real application so that the work isn't wasted, just duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of good advice (and a huge number of sample benchmarks for different languages) at http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/

C.

Comment: I could not reach the site, probably the link is broken. I have found the https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/index.html benchmark site which is working as of today.

Comment: While you could probably find it on the wayback machine, the metrics would be a long way out of date - C and Java won't have changed much but current Python and PHP should be very different.

Answer (score 2):

Better take one of the existing benchmarks:

http://www.sellersrank.com/web-frameworks-benchmarking-results/

http://avnetlabs.com/php/php-framework-comparison-benchmarks

http://www.yiiframework.com/performance/

http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+benchmark+frameworks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox

But if you really need to find out what framework will be faster for YOUR project - you will need to write a model of your project using that framework and test on it.

Comment: Some of the benchmark links are broken.

Comment: Well, time is merciless. It's 2024 now ;) My post was dated 2010 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will spend a lot of time and come to realization that it was all wasted.
After you complete your tests you will learn that loops of 1000000 empty iterations are far from the real life and come to apache benchmark.
Then you come no know of opcode cachers which will ruin all your previous results.
Then you will learn that single DB query will take 1000 times longer time than API call, so, your comparisons of database access methods are really waste.
Then you will learn of memcache which will allow you just jump over some terrible bottlenecks you've discovered already, etc etc etc

Comment: Caching helps, but it's not an option that's available to everyone. I'll also re-test everything with caching set up.

Comment: I also disagree that empty iterations are useless. They measure overhead is inherit to the language itself. That is interesting information.

Comment: He has a point. Benchmarks usually tell very little about real-world performance, especially since web applications usually involve much IO, and IO performance is mostly language/framework-agnostic.

Comment: @delnan - You can subtract out the IO part though if you have tests that enable you to see what the lower levels impact is.